# Showing that a sequence containing the floor function follows an equality

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Show that $\Big \lfloor \frac{n+1}{ 2 } \Big \rfloor + \Big \lfloor
> \frac{n+2}{ 2^2 } \Big \rfloor + \Big \lfloor \frac{n+2^2}{ 2^3 } \Big
>  \rfloor + \dotsb + \Big \lfloor \frac{n+2^k}{ 2^{k+1} } \Big \rfloor
>  +\dotsb = n$, for every positive integer n. Note that this is not an infinite sum since  $0<\dfrac{n+2^k}{ 2^{k+1} }<1$  for sufficiently
> large k, which makes all terms from there equal 0.

This is my attempt:

Consider the first 3 terms:

$$\left\lfloor \bigg(\frac{n}{2}+\frac12\bigg)\right\rfloor, \ \left\lfloor\bigg(\frac{n}{4}+\frac12\bigg)\right\rfloor, \ \left\lfloor\bigg(\frac{n}{8}+\frac12\bigg)\right\rfloor.$$

Hence, we can represent the series as the finite sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor\frac{n+2^{k-1}}{2^k}\right\rfloor$$

Consider the first 4 cases:

$n=1$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\lfloor\frac{1+2^{k-1}}{2^k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2^k}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2^{k-1}}{2^k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2^{k}}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

$n=2$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\lfloor\frac{2+2^{k-1}}{2^k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{2}{2^k}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2^{k-1}}{2^k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

$n=3$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\lfloor\frac{3+2^{k-1}}{2^k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{3}{2^k}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2^{k-1}}{2^k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{3}{2^k}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

$n=4$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\lfloor\frac{4+2^{k-1}}{2^k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{4}{2^k}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2^{k-1}}{2^k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{2}{2^{k-2}}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

For the terms $\frac{1}{2^k},\cdots,\frac{2}{2^{k-2}}$ we obtain 0, $\forall\  k\geq1$ and since $\left\lfloor
\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor=0$, we obtain all terms equal to zero, $\forall\  k\geq1$.

But this is wrong.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n+2}{4}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n+4}{8}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n+8}{16}\rfloor+ \dots=n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821536/prove-that-lfloor-fracn12-rfloor-lfloor-fracn24-rfloor-lfloor-frac) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clfloor%5Cfrac%7Bn%2B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Crfloor%2B%5Clfloor%5Cfrac%7Bn%2B2%7D%7B2%5E2%7D%5Crfloor%2B%5Cldots%2B%5Clfloor%20%5Cfrac%7Bn%2B2%5Ek%7D%7B2%5E%7Bk%2B1%7D%7D%5Crfloor%2B%5Cldots%3Dn%24&p=1). There are also other ...

Comment: $\lfloor a+b \rfloor = \lfloor a \rfloor + \lfloor b \rfloor$ is not true in general.

Comment: (cont.) duplicates, e.g., [Sum of (Almost) Infinite Geometric Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3150456) and [Prove that $\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2}{2^2}}\bigg\rfloor+\ldots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2882804). In addition, there's the AoPS thread [pm of Olympiad about $\lfloor x\rfloor$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h34668p215131) (with its Post #$2$ stating this problem is from IMO $1968$-$6$).

Comment: You switched somewhere from $2^k$ to $2k$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan no, it doesn't answer it since we have a k-variable to consider in the finite sum.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz Note the $k$ variable is just a dummy variable representing a particular term in the sum. The other duplicate questions could have been rewritten in the same manner as yours, with it still representing the *same* set of terms and, thus, also the *same* series and sum value of $n$. As such, the other posts do provide answers to your question.

Comment: @JohnOmielan The original equality can be written as : 
$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor=n$$, which means that the fraction with $2^k$ will always be a fraction, unless for $k=0$.  Then the LHS will be $n+\frac{1}{2}$, which still is not equal to  $n$. So how do we use the limit as in the post you  mentioned on this?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz Actually, each term is $\left\lfloor\frac{n+2^k}{2^{k+1}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{2^k}{2^{k+1}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^{\color{red}{k+1}}}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$, i.e., you have the exponent for $2$ incorrect. Thus, starting with $k=0$, we get $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$ (i.e., $\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor$, the first term in both your and the other question's summation). This is, for even $n$, $\frac{n}{2}$ and, for odd $n$, $\frac{n+1}{2}$, both of which are considerably less than $n$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan  Thanks for pointing out that error. We can use the equality $\lfloor x\rfloor=x-\{x\}$  on the term given, and consider the case of $k=0$ and write:

$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor=\frac{n}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2}-\left\{\frac{n}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2}\right\}$$

$$\frac{n}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2}-\left\{\frac{n}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2}\right\}=n$$

Put $k=0$ and obtain:


$$\frac{n}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2}-\left\{\frac{n}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2}\right\}=n$$ But the latter is false..

Comment: @Luthier415Hz Note it's *not* any one particular term, with any particular $k$ value (including $0$), that's equal to $n$, but rather the sum of all of the terms of that form (with the larger ones becoming $0$, as you've already noted, so the actual sum is finite). I'm unsure why you think otherwise. Also, note I will not communicate anything else with you re: this question's problem. I suggest you review and carefully reconsider everything yourself.

Comment: @JohnOmielan so far  no answers have been given to this post.